# Does a transformed Dart app need to be one file?

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart-pub

Lets say I'm making an app where I need to push updates to the client-side regularly. Now most of these update would only ever affect my own code, never the libraries that form up my dependancies. As far as I'm aware, the transformer I'll use when invoking `pub build`, will take all my libraries, dependancies, and whatever else, and compile them together in a single `web/main.dart.js` file. This tends to remind me somewhat of ***static linking***, as with languages like C++.

For obvious reasons, compiling like this is something you'd only want to do when finally deploying an app. For most people, it suffices to just use dartium and work off the `.dart` hierarchy directly. However, what if I were *testing* in a javascript browser, trying out `dart:js` code, for instance. I wouldn't want to have to recompile all of angular and friends, when they go entirely untouched. My specific case is the desire to use CDN services for static files within my app.

AngularDart, as my example, contributes a massive *22,000 lines* to my compiled javascript, and if I change one little thing within my own app, I can kiss `304 NOT MODIFIED` goodbye, let alone CDN savings, for that bulk of untouched angular.

All that being said, is there a way to de-couple dependancies in a transformed dart application? **Can I "*dynamicly link*" my dart libraries?** And furthermore, could I hypothetically distribute my dart libraries as `dart.js`, for use in other transformed code?

Comment: To reduce load times you can split into multiple files using deferred loading. There is also work happening on incremental compiling in dart2js so that only the code changed needs to be recompiled. This improves compile times during testing. There is no way to "dynamically link" dart libraries in a way that solves your CDN use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't work this way. This could work if the deployable contained the entire dependencies but that's not the case.
pub build includes only the code that's actually used in your app (tree shaking) and this is usually only a small fraction  of a dependency. Changing a single character in your code can require including different code from your dependencies. I think treeshaking has a much bigger effect than caching could have.

Comment: Understandable, however I feel that certain libraries can end up having more live-code than dead; that's the general ideal anyway. As it is right now, libraries can contribute immense bulk to an app, which is why I ask. Even a simple hello-world and end up enormous, and you'd think there was plenty of dead code. I understand your take, but I personally disagree that tree shaking is any more than insubstantial at this point. This is especially true when a compiled hello-world angular app is larger than its JS counterparts combined...

Comment: Tree-shaking usually works quite well. When your build output is too large there might be something wrong with your build process or with your code or code in dependencies (use of mirrors). As far as I know a hello world becomes about 200k (without Angular, don't remember with Angular). If that is enormous for your Dart is probably not the right tool for your project. If your output is much bigger than there is probably something wrong with how you build. Usually from this initial size, the size doesn't grow fast by adding custom code.